# java.lang.NumberFormatException in trying to load a file

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I've been getting this error while trying to load certain data from a txt file.

```
public static boolean initalize(String FileName) {
    String line = "";

    String token = "";

    String token2 = "";

    String token2_2 = "";

    String[] token3 = new String[10];

    boolean EndOfFile = false;

    BufferedReader characterfile = null;

    try {

            characterfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./Data/data/"

                            + FileName));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileex) {
        Misc.println("File not loaded");

            return false;

    }

    try {

            line = characterfile.readLine();

    } catch (IOException ioexception) {


            return false;

    }

    while ((EndOfFile == false) && (line != null)) {

            **line = line.trim();
            int spot = line.indexOf("=");
            if (spot > -1) {
                    token = line.substring(0, spot);
                    token = token.trim();
                    token2 = line.substring(spot + 1);
                    token2 = token2.trim();
                    token2_2 = token2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                    token2_2 = token2_2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                    token2_2 = token2_2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                    token2_2 = token2_2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                    token2_2 = token2_2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                    token3 = token2_2.split("\t");**

                    if (token.equals("drop")) {

                            int id = Integer.parseInt(token3[0]);

                            int x = Integer.parseInt(token3[1]);

                            int y = Integer.parseInt(token3[2]);

                            int amount = Integer.parseInt(token3[3]);

                            int height = Integer.parseInt(token3[4]);
                            globalDrops.add(new GlobalDrop(id,amount,x,y,height));  

                    }

            } else {

                    if (line.equals("[ENDOFDROPLIST]")) {

                            try {

                                    characterfile.close();

                            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

                            }

                            return true;

                    }

            }

            try {

                    line = characterfile.readLine();

            } catch (IOException ioexception1) {

                    EndOfFile = true;

            }

    }

    try {

            characterfile.close();

    } catch (IOException ioexception) {

    }

    return false;

}
```

However, its been giving me this error:

```
[8/3/12 5:24 PM]: Exception in thread "main" [8/3/12 5:24 PM]: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1923     3208    3214    1       0       2       "
```

This is how the text file is formated:

```
sque = 1923     3208    3214    1       0       2       Square
```

Why is this giving me the error? Is it something to do with the /t/ splits?

Thanks

This is the working one:

```
sque = 1923 3208    3214    1   0   2       Square
```

However, I'm trying to load over 400 of these and it would be painful to change all of them at once

Comment: The version you pasted is delimited with spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all this

```
                token = line.substring(0, spot);
                token = token.trim();
                token2 = line.substring(spot + 1);
                token2 = token2.trim();
                token2_2 = token2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                token2_2 = token2_2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                token2_2 = token2_2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                token2_2 = token2_2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                token2_2 = token2_2.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
                token3 = token2_2.split("\t");**
```

with

```
String[] cmd = line.split("=");
token = cmd[0].trim;
String[] numbers = cmd[1].split("\\s+");
```

The array `numbers` will contains the numeric string tokens, already trimmed and ready to be interpreted by `Integer.parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the exception that whatever is being passed into an int conversion routine is not parseable integer.

It actually looks like your program is not properly parsing input string leaving the sequence of numbers in it, possibly because of your use of "\t". I would check with regex to see if you can actually find these tabs and split this file properly, before converting to ints.

You could also, to be a defensive programmer, check if string is convertable to int before you actually convert it to int.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String aStringValue) {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "\\d+" );
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(aStringValue);
   return matcher.matches();
```

}

Also, just for debugging try:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\t","|");
```

and see how it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Right because this:

```
"1923     3208    3214    1       0       2       "
```

is not a number.  The exception seems pretty clear - you need to tokenize that line into the number parts, then parse each individually.